# Ubuntu is not detecting previous OS partitions

Tags: 13.04, windows-8

I have a 2 TB hard disk. I have installed Windows 8 in 200 GB space, and leave more 800 GB for it, formatted as NTFS.

My idea was to install the Ubuntu 13.04 in the left 1 TB.

The issue is that the Ubuntu installer is showing to me a 2 TB free space - it is not detecting that the hard drive has been already partitioned.

What should I do in order to achieve my goal and have Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 8?

EDIT:

I have follow the advice below and open gparted in "try Ubuntu" mode. It gives me the following question with 'yes/no' options:

```
/dev/sda contains GPT signatures indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it
should. Perhaps it was corrupted - possible by a program that doesn't
understand GPT partition tables. Or perhaps, you deleted the GPT
table, and are now using un msdos partition table. Is this a GPT
partion table?
```

Comment: why don't you try doing "try Ubuntu" while boot up to get to the live desktop and open gparted and see whats happening with your partitions ..it may help you....

Answer (score 0):

Both the Ubuntu installer and GParted use the libparted library from the parted project for partitioning.

In order for the Ubuntu installer and GParted to correctly see the partition table, the partition table must be fixed.

This means that you will need to decide whether you are using an GPT or an MSDOS partition table.

To view MSDOS partition table entries use:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

where /dev/sda is the device name of your 2 TB disk.

To view GUID partition table entries use:

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

where /dev/sda is the device name of your 2 TB disk.