# Previous OS not detected at installation

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, uefi, detect

I've read some other threads with the same issue, not being able to solve my problem.

When I try to install Ubuntu with a USB, it does not recognize the OS I have already installed (Windows 8). I want a dual-boot system, I don't want to replace the one I already have.

It's a new notebook where I'm installing it into.

I've read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI but it does not state this problem I'm having. I don't know if I have to make a new partition (or how), or what else to do.
I have also read this [Ubuntu is not detecting previous OS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340499/ubuntu-is-not-detecting-previous-os-partitions) but I don't understand what to do once I type what it says.

I would install it buy using Wubi but it fails on the middle of the instalation.

[image]

Comment: **1)** Don't use Wubi - **ESPECIALLY ON WINDOWS 8**. It is deprecated and buggy anyway. **2)** Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Try another version, see if that helps. **3)** On the Live USB, click 'Try Ubuntu' and then search for 'Disk' or 'GParted'. Open it, and then add what it shows to a comment or your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and the fatalistic warning.

Here's the screen from GParted:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzP3p8W8jJbKLVlSazd6UXY3NEU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Wubi in an unsupported manner.

Comment: This question has generated "close" votes that refer to three different questions. Ironically, the [first question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) *does not address this question's problem.* The [second question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371783/ubuntu-does-not-offers-me-install-alongside-windows) is also inapplicable because it assumes a BIOS-mode install, whereas this one is clearly EFI-mode. Only the [third question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376710/live-usb-for-ubuntu-13-10-doest-recognize-windows-8-os) addresses the issue (and that rather tersely).