# Ubuntu cannot detect Windows 7 so I cannot dual-boot

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, 13.10, windows-7

I wanted to dual boot my Windows 7 (x64) with Ubuntu 13.10 (x64). When I get to the stage when I select a partition, it says that Ubuntu does not detect any other operating system in my computer. I chose 'Something else' and the only partition that came up was 'free space' with 500 GB free space (my hard drive space). I set two partitions before installing Ubuntu. 414 GB for Windows 7 and 50 GB for Ubuntu.
My disk is not Dynamic.

Comment: I would not usually do this, but this is a possible duplicate of ['Previous OS not detected'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378586/previous-os-not-detected-at-installation), which itself is a duplicate of several other questions. Hope you find the info there helpful anyway.

Comment: Hello @wilf , I have already looked at those and a lot of other questions but none of them helped.

Comment: exit the ubuntu installer,install gparted and upload its screenshot to imgur.com then post the lin here.

Comment: Hello @AvinashRaj I installed qparted and I uploaded [screenshots](http://imgur.com/8F6SXYv,9XVZp8G#1) to imgur.

Comment: What filesystem is your Windows partition using?

Comment: @MDMoore313 Sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: what's your hard disk space?what was the other option shown on clicking the top right corner of the gparted screenshot?

Comment: Is your Windows machine formatted using NTFS, exFAT, etc.?

Comment: @MDMoore313 My Windows machine is formatted using NTFS.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I booted back into gparted. [Here is the screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/T8EGf0B.jpg). The first one is my Hard Drive. The second and third are USBs for Ubuntu and GParted.

Comment: Is your Windows partition encrypted?

Comment: @MDMoore313 How can I check if it is encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From the screenshot,it was clearly shown that you accidentally deleted the previously installed Windows partition.

So exit the ubuntu installer and create new partitions for windows and Ubuntu using Gparted Partition Editor.

After that run the ubuntu installer then choose "something else" option and select the created ext4 partition for installing Ubuntu.And don't forget to create a swap partition of size which was double the RAM size(applicable for 1 or 2 GB RAM).

Comment: Hello but it is not deleted or anything. Windows actually still loads from the same computer after I rebooted after taking that screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to recover data from that disk try to do so BEFORE INSTALLING ANOTHER OS. There are tons of disk recovery tools out there, just an fyi. The files are probably still there, just the filesystem information was erased.

Comment: I see. What recovery tool do you recommend?

Comment: I've only worked with one in the past, so I can't be of much help. For reference, it was [PC Tools File Recover](http://www.pctools.com/product-eol/index/faq/utility/), and I'm saddened to report that they've just discontinued their *entire* line, including Registry Mechanic. *\*teardrop*\*.